# How can I convert(or adapt) a Text-User Interface to a GUI (Java)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I have a large Java project(a SQL-backed personnel system, in Java 6) with a Text Interface which is fairly complex. For example, in the main class when the user picks the person option, it will call this code:

```
    int choice = new Integer(line);
    if(choice >= 1 && choice <= 13){  
        exit = false;
        models[choice - 1].showMenu();
    }
```

And then it eventually calls the Person class, whose constructor looks like this:

```
  public Person(Connection con){
    conn = con;
    item = "Person";
    count = getLastID() + 1;
  }
```

and a sample menu option to get all of a person's info looks like so:

```
  protected void queryGetAll(){
      Statement stmnt = null;
      // create prepared statement
      try {
          stmnt = conn.createStatement();
          ResultSet result = stmnt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM person");
          System.out.println("");
          System.out.println("");
          System.out.println(" *****************       LIST OF ALL PERSONS      ***************** ");
          System.out.println("");
          while(result.next()){
              System.out.print(" ID: " + result.getString("per_id") + "   |   ");
              System.out.print(" NAME: " + result.getString("name") + "   |   ");
              System.out.print(" STREET: " + result.getString("street") + "   |   ");
              System.out.print(" CITY: " + result.getString("city") + "   |   ");
              System.out.print(" ZIP CODE: " + result.getString("zip_code") + "   |   ");
              System.out.print(" E-MAIL: " + result.getString("email") + "   |   ");
              System.out.println(" GENDER: " + result.getString("gender"));
          }
          System.out.println("");
          System.out.println("");
          stmnt.close();
        } catch(SQLException ex) {
          System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
  }
```

I want to convert this whole TUI into a GUI using NetBeans, which makes GUI building easy. The issue is I don't know how to "grab" the results, i.e, what do I put in the GUI code here:

```
this.textBox.setText("The person's information" + iDontKnowWhatsHere  );
```

Is there any work-around here? If it's possible to grab what by default is put onto the console, and just shoot it to the GUI text-box I'd be happy to do that. Any guidance/tips appreciated, Thanks

Comment: ..i guess this is hard right?

Comment: I think, the system you are talking about, have so many wonder factor. Netbeans will add same amount of wonder factor. Be realistic, from my experience its evil to use any tools to design UI. Create your own...

Comment: So by "wonder factor" you mean it's just too complex and messy to get this working as I'd like, ya? The thing is I can't design my own GUI, it's just too much(over 10 classes)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most suitable component here is JTable.

Create one Vector of String as columns ' names and Vector of Vector for the table data.
Main Vector contain rows (also Vectors) and each rowVector has all the row values.

Then create a DefaultTableModel and a JTable based on the model (JTable also has construtor to pass the columns and data)

Comment: I'm not really understanding, but it seems to be a good solution. JTable is a pop-up window I guess?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html or http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1000__JTable.htm

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing that can "convert" the TUI  to GUI for you. In Swing, you will need to use JLabel(s). If you want to display just one person's data, you could create different JLabel for each property, like lblID, lblName. Then you can set the values of these label's based on your query's result:

```
JLabel lblID= new JLabel();
lbl.setText(result.getString("per_id"));
JLabel lblName = new JLabel();
lblName.setText(result.getString("name"));
```

If you want to display result of multiple persons, you can have a look at [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)